# SSRS Export To Word Option

Tags: sql-server, wpf, reporting-services

Our WPF Application using SSRS Report.
We export SSRS report to word header logo image alignment going wrong.

SSRS report logo show in right side corner. But after export to word
logo come to center. Right side alignment missing.

Comment: Is the width of the report the same as the word document?

Comment: Both width are same size.